# How to refresh DataSource bean when using JPA?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, datasource, hikaricp

I am refreshing the Hikari datasource after every 1 minute of interval. I am using the spring data JPA for performing the save operations. But JPA is pointing to older bean of datasource and I am getting below exceptions.

```
java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (hikariConnectionPool0) has been closed.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:96)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:269)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at
```

This is used to close datasource.

((HikariDataSource) dataSource).close()

This is used to create new datasource.

dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

Comment: Why are you refreshing the datasource, that seems weird. How are you refreshing, please post the datasource and refresh logic you are using.

Comment: I need to refresh it as we are using some credentials which are required to establish the connection to postgres. They are getting refreshed after 1 minute so I need to refresh the datasource.

Comment: Don't. Wrap it in a `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter` and just update the username/password in that. Also don't use the Spring Boot auto configured datasource as that makes zero sense in this scenario. Just use the dumb `DriverManagerDataSource` or `SimpleDriverDataSource` and configure it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your credentials are refreshed every 1 minute then don't use the Spring Boot auto-configured `DataSource`. That is a `HikariDataSource` and is an actual connection pool. Closing and refreshing it won't work as you cannot re-set the references that are already there. Also re-connecting to the database will also take a while, in which the password might have been reset.

Instead use the `DriverManagerDataSource` and wrap it in a `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`. Then every minute update the `username` and `password` in the `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`.

```java
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource(DataSourceProperties props) {
  DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
  ds.setUrl(props.getUrl());
  ds.setDriverClassName(props.determineDriverClassName());
  return ds;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSource(DriverManagerDataSource ds) {
  UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dsa = new UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter();
  dsa.setTargetDataSource(ds);
  return dsa;
}
```

With this you can set the `username` and `password` accordingly and when a connection is needed it will be using those.

```java
public class DataSourceUpdater {

  private final UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dsa;

  public DataSourceUpdater(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dsa) {
    this.dsa=dsa;
  }

  public void doIt() {
    var username = //obtain new username
    var password = //obtain new password
    syncronized(dsa) {
      dsa.setUsername(username);
      dsa.setPassword(password);
    }
  }
}
```